# Runcell in Spyder not working with split panes

Tags: python, ipython, spyder

Strange issue. Running Spyder 4.1.3, I open a new file and type something simple like this.

```
print(1)
#%%

print(2)
#%%
```

Then I hit shift-enter (twice) in the editor, and it runs one cell at a time, like it's supposed to:

```
In [1]: print(1)
1

In [2]: print(2)
2
```

Then I split the editor pane, and I focus on the new editor pane, and again hit shift-enter, but this time it runs the entire file at once, ignoring cell delimiters:

```
In [3]: print(1)
   ...: #%%
   ...: 
   ...: print(2)
   ...: 
   ...: #%%
1
2
```

In other words, runcell only works correctly on the original editor pane, not the second pane after the split.

I first noticed this happening when I restarted Spyder after a crash, but I'm not sure if that is what caused it or not. I've tried restarting Spyder, resetting defaults, and the behavior hasn't changed. Anyone have any idea what is going on?